# Thunderbird: emoji covers my mail

Tags: emoji, thunderbird

Good evening,

i've just installed thunderbird on my ubuntu and imported the mailboxes from another linux distributions and when i open my default mailbox some mails are covered by stickers as in [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDfnu.png). How can i solve this issue?

Regards,

Gunnar

Comment: I would suggest to take this question to: https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

You can remove emoji support by `sudo apt-get remove fonts-noto-color-emoji`

Also you can remove ***/usr/lib/firefox/fonts/EmojiOneMozilla.ttf***